# EC2 instance not coming up after reboot

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I noticed this morning that one of my aws EC2 instances was running way too slow, so I just thought that I would reboot the instance.

After rebooting it never came back though and pinging the public IP returns a "Request timeout".

I really feel like I've hit a dead end. Any bright suggestions on how to solve this issue?

Comment: rebooted or re-started (stop/start)? If the second, the IP could have changed.

Comment: It was rebooted and the IP is still the same

Comment: So just spin up new one. In cloud its much easier to get rid of broken instances, and create new ones, then trying to recover them.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up stopping the instance and starting it again. I read that a full stop of the instance changes the physical hardware the instance is on, while a reboot is just a reboot of the OS.

After starting again, I just had to update my dns records as the instance got a new IP.